# Render content to dynamic layout programmatically from shape override in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I want to add LayoutPart to BlogPost content type. But as you know content of blog post would not be rendered in layout, so i decided to override shape of blogpost. What i need is to render layout and put blogpost content inside of it. Is there a way to do that programmatically?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here. The LayoutPart can be used to give the specific item a different layout than the rest of the items. If you want your blogposts to all look the same, but different than it is now, create a Content-BlogPost alternate. Please elaborate (in your question!!) exactly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I am trying to use dynamic layout for blog post. If you just add LayoutPart to Blog Post then it will rendered like that
1. Blog post; 2. Layout Part. 3. Then comments.
I want blog post part rendered inside dynamic layout

Comment: Did you remove the BodyPart? The LayoutPart isn't magically going to change the appereance, you have to actually use it like you do with pages and define a layout, and insert your content there